# Creating a tree graph in igraph

Tags: r, tree, igraph

I am trying to create a genealogical tree in igraph (R), and I used the following code:

```
id = 1:5
parent = c(1,1,2,3,3)
name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
data = data.frame(id, parent, name)
n = graph.data.frame(data)
co=layout.reingold.tilford(n, flip.y=T)
plot <- plot.igraph(g,layout=co, vertex.label = name)
```

D and E should both have parent C, but this code often plots D and E on top of each other with only one arrow (instead of two). Does anybody have the solution for this problem?

[image]

Comment: Clear your workspace/restart R. The object `g` used in the last line is not defined in the above code. I guess it should be `n`. If so, it looks right to me.

Comment: Alas, this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Is important that you use `layout.reingold.tilford` to layout the graph? It is stochastic and seems somewhat unstable.

Comment: Ah maybe that is the reason why.. I don't think it's necessary, it's just something that I have seen in other people's codes. I'll take a look at it, thank you..

Answer (score 1):

First, you seem to specify the `data.frame` incorrectly to get your graph. 
The first and second column of `data` specify the vertices the edges run `from` and `to`, respectively. So, to get D and E as children of C, you need to have the `parents` in the first column.
Secondly, you just specify the labels/name directly the the `data.frame`.
I got this to work:

```
library("igraph")
data <- data.frame(parent = LETTERS[c(1,1,2,3,3)], id = LETTERS[1:5])
g <- graph.data.frame(data)

myformat <- function(g) {
  layout.reingold.tilford(g, root = 1, flip.y = FALSE, circular = FALSE)
}
plot(g, layout = myformat)
```

[image: Imgur]

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I also had problems with that plotting command (not an interactive way of plotting), but I've started using `tkplot` (http://igraph.org/r/doc/tkplot.html) since then.

Check this version:

```
library(igraph)

id = 1:5
parent = c(1,1,2,3,3)
name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
data = data.frame(id, parent, name)
g = graph.data.frame(data)
tkplot(g, vertex.color="red", vertex.label=name)
```

You should get something like:

[image]

You can move the nodes (drag them), click on the arrows, change their colour (all or specific nodes), etc. Very good for visualisation. You might find some problems when you deal with very big graphs.

Just to be clear though, the problem you have in your code seems to be created by the layout command. If you just do:

```
library(igraph)

id = 1:5
parent = c(1,1,2,3,3)
name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
data = data.frame(id, parent, name)
g = graph.data.frame(data)
plot <- plot.igraph(g,vertex.label = name)
```

You should get :

[image]

which is exactly like `tkplot`, but it doesn't allow you to change the shape or other elements on the actual plot.